# What's the JS syntax to call a native module that has a single Promise parameter?

Tags: javascript, java, react-native, promise

The Java signature is declared as:

```
@ReactMethod
public void someMethod(@NonNull String aString, @NonNull final Promise promise);
```

In that case, the Javascript calls it like this:

```
async someMethod() {
    try {
      var result = await MyModule.someMethod("Hello",)
      ...
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

This works.

Now I have another method that looks like:

```
@ReactMethod
public void someOtherMethod(@NonNull final Promise promise);
```

And I cannot call it from JS because it complains (the errors are very cryptic for an inexperienced JS developer like me). I'm not looking forwards becoming a proficient JS developer, this is a small project I need to help with, but I cannot figure out how to call that.

I've tried variations of:

```
var result = await MyModule.someOtherMethod()
var result = await MyModule.someOtherMethod(,)
var result = await MyModule.someOtherMethod({})
...
```

Most examples I see either use `Callback` (not a `Promise`) or *always and conveniently* have more than one parameter, where the promise is (by design) the last parameter. But I couldn't find a single example with a method that *only* takes a Promise.

It could be I don't know how to search... (?)

Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: can you add the `error` too in question and also how `someOtherMethod` method is defined ?

Comment: Unless the method implementation itself handle such cases, you will have to pass the promise as the second argument. A major reason for this is there is no method overloading in javascript.

Comment: @AayushSharma what do you mean by _handle such cases_? I mean, if the signature is `someOtherMethod(Promise p)`, then you cannot call it like that from JS? (can it be called differently?) or is the other parameter there to overcome the lack of method overloading? (meaning I can't have `methodA(int x, Promise p)` and `methodB(int y, Promise p)`?)

Comment: @CodeManiac the error was a JS syntax error or similar, honestly it's was all buried in every attempt of me calling it, but the whole react-native JS code exploded with my attempts to use the -incorrect- syntax. The method definitions are in the question, this is pseudo code, they look like that.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I did create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5bnt3r9k/) for a case where implementation handles the argument order. There is no overloading in javascript and no static typing so implementation has to handle such cases in javascript. Otherwise, the parameter order matters in javascript and it has to be the second parameter if such cases are not handled in implementation.

Comment: @AayushSharma Thanks. I also tried again today, and it works if you call `someMethod()` no params. I guess I was making some other mistake and CodeManiac question about what the error was, made me re-investigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm vote-closing this, but for future reference in case it doesn't pass, the *expected* syntax:

```
await module.someMethod()
```

Worked when calling a `@ReactMethod` method whose signature looks like

```
void someMethod(@NonNull Promise p);
```

I have no idea what black magic(*) I did but now it works.

(*)
For the most part, I noticed what when using react-native, it's more often than not, useful to kill the "metro" server and restart it with `react-native start --reset-cache` and then run the app again. This has made my otherwise non-compiling/running project to finally compile/run ok many times when other solutions didn't work.

I also executed this command a few times during my time with react-native, as it did fix many compile errors that appeared when I did certain things (not sure which).

```
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

After that a normal `react-native run-android` usually worked (or a run from Android Studio).

From there (and while using a real device with Vysor), I got the menu to "reload" and other things by issuing in the command line:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Thanks for the help and hope this points other people in the right direction.